# Is that possible to remove the ripple effect in MDIconButton in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Is that possible to remove the ripple effect in MDIconButton in KivyMD ?

I am trying to develop a application using python KivyMD , for better user experience I would like to remove the rippling effect of MDIconButton

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout



class MainWidget(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
MainWidget:
    RelToolBar:

<RelToolBar@RelativeLayout>:
    size_hint: 1,.05
    pos_hint: {'x':0 , 'top':1 }
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, .4
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    MDIconButton:
        halign: "center"
        icon: "menu"
        theme_text_color: "Primary"
        pos_hint: {'x':0 , 'center_y':.5 }
    MDLabel:
        text: "T E S T"
        theme_text_color: "Primary"
        halign: 'center'
        font_style: "Caption"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can remove it, but you can hide it by changing the size of the `RippleBehavior` to 0:

```
MDIconButton:
    ripple_scale: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly disable it by setting `_no_ripple_effect = True`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Not sure why this property is prepended by an underscore, it can / should be used in the .kv file to control this effect.